# Script generates several descriptions instead of one

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I use short description generator plugin for my Magento 1.7, and it works a bit wrong. The following code is from "ProductController.php":

getRequest()->getParam('product');

```
    foreach ($pIds as $pId) {
        $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_product=$obj->load($pId);
        $attribs=$_product->getAttributes();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($attribs as $attrib) {

            if ($attrib->getUsedInProductListing() && $attrib->getIsUserDefined()) {

                $prodAttrVal=$attrib->getStoreLabel().': ';
                $pa=$attrib->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                //$pa=$_product->getAttributeText($attrib->getAttributeCode());
                if ($pa==null) $pa='не указано';
                $prodAttrVal.=$pa;
                if ($i % 2==0) $str.=' '.$prodAttrVal.' | ';
                else $str.=' '.$prodAttrVal.'.';
                $i++;
            }

        }
        if ($i % 2!=0) $str.=' ';
        $str.=' ';
        $_product->setDescription($str);
        $obj->save();
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_massupdate_after', array('products'=>$pIds));
    $this->_redirect('adminhtml/catalog_product/index/', array());
}
```

}

When I choose N products in catalog and select "Generate Short Description", script generates short description by following pattern: "Attr1: blah. Attr2: blah. Attr3: blah. Attr1: blah. Attr2: blah. Attr3: blah." -- repeated N times in some products, but in other products it makes only one description, as it have to be in right case. Similarity of product names or SKU's does not depends.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in this line

```
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //this line

   foreach ($pIds as $pId) {

        $_product=$obj->load($pId);
        $attribs=$_product->getAttributes();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($attribs as $attrib) {

            if ($attrib->getUsedInProductListing() && $attrib->getIsUserDefined()) {

                $prodAttrVal=$attrib->getStoreLabel().': ';
                $pa=$attrib->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                //$pa=$_product->getAttributeText($attrib->getAttributeCode());
                if ($pa==null) $pa='не указано';
                $prodAttrVal.=$pa;
                if ($i % 2==0) $str.=' '.$prodAttrVal.' | ';
                else $str.=' '.$prodAttrVal.'.';
                $i++;
            }

        }
        if ($i % 2!=0) $str.=' ';
        $str.=' ';
        $_product->setDescription($str);
        $_product->save();
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_massupdate_after', array('products'=>$pIds));
    $this->_redirect('adminhtml/catalog_product/index/', array());
}
```

Let me know if you have query

Comment: Sorry, but it not worked. And situation now is a bit worse: repeated attributes in description now are mixed from different products, which were chosen in catalog. E.g.: "Samsung Galaxy SIII Red" and "Samsung Galaxy SIII White" (SKUs are the same) in short description have: "Color: Red; ....(other attributes skipped)...Color: White;....".